# Weird set screw on tub faucet

Tags: faucet, screws, bathtub

I’m trying to remove this old tub faucet. There is what looks to be a set screw, but it’s either been stripped or is super corroded. What are my options here? I can’t seem to fit an Allen key down there.

Picture attached.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIB8d.jpg]

Comment: Try a google search for "easy out screw extractor."  You can find them at Home Depot and Lowe's and probably most, other hardware stores too.  It looks like you would need a really small one.

Comment: Or, it's so corroded, drill it out completely.

Comment: It's hard to say for sure, but it could be a hex-head screw, requiring a socket. It would be _quite_ odd, but someone may have done a "fix" at a previous time, and with all that corrosion... I'm in the "drill it out" camp, though.

Comment: Look s like drilling it out is the option. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are removing this unit to replace with a new unit, then I would either:

1. drill out the setscrew - not much care needed as it’s being replaced. But if it was to be re-used then putting the drill in a jig to save the threads would help.
2. just use a grinder to cut the old unit up - protect the worktop and surrounding surfaces from the debris.